# Deserializing links collection to a dictionary

Tags: json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the output from a REST API call.  A fragment of the JSON is here:

```
    "_links": {
        "invoices": {
            "href": "url",
            "type": "application/json"
        },
        "members": {
            "href": "otherurl",
            "type": "application/json"
        },
        "paymentCard": {
            "href": "yetanotherurl",
            "type": "application/json"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "evenmoreurl",
            "type": "application/json"
        },
        "session": {
            "href": "andyesevenmoreurl",
            "type": "application/json"
        },
        "subscription": {
            "href": "tiredofurls",
            "type": "application/json"
        }
    }
```

I would like to deserialize it to a dictionary of the following class:

```
public class Link
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Href {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

The dictionary would be

```
Dictionary<string, Link> = new Dictionary<string, Link>();
```

where the Name property is the key

I'm trying to use Newtonsoft's JSON Serializer.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the dictionary you want like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Link> dict = JObject.Parse(json)
    .SelectToken(".._links")
    .Children<JProperty>()
    .ToDictionary(jp => jp.Name, jp => new Link()
    {
        Name = jp.Name,
        Href = (string)jp.Value["href"],
        Type = (string)jp.Value["type"]
    });
```

Here, I am using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse the JSON into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).  I use the [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method with a [JsonPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to recursively find the first node called "_links" anywhere in the JSON.  From there, I get the child properties and convert it to a dictionary of links as you described.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HBjm51

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  How would that work if the JSON segment I specified is part of a larger JSON string?

Comment: In that case you would want to use `SelectToken` (instead of the square-bracket syntax I originally showed in my answer) to navigate down to the correct node in the JSON.  I've updated my answer with more detail.